# I am trying to duplicate cnn and merge them, so that I get a dual path architecture. But getting error. I am using keras 2.1.6 version

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ipython, conv-neural-network

Need  help with python coding.I tried to concatenate 2 CNN models. model #1 has 3 convolution layers followed by a dense layer. model2 also has the same architecture. I m trying to concatenate the output of these cnns and have another dense layer. I am including the code for your kind reference.

```
model1 = Sequential()
# Conv Layer 1
model1.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(32, (9, 9), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model1.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# Conv Layer 2
model1.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(64, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model1.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# Conv Layer 3
model1.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(128, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model1.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# model.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(256, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
# model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# Flatten the data for upcoming dense layer
model1.add(layers.Flatten())

model1.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model1.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
#model1.add(layers.Dense(output_classes,) activation='relu'))
#model1.build(input_shape = (input_shape)


model2 = Sequential()
# Conv Layer 1
model2.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(32, (9, 9), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# Conv Layer 2
model2.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(64, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# Conv Layer 3
model2.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(128, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# model.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(256, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
# model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# Flatten the data for upcoming dense layer
model2.add(layers.Flatten())

model2.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
#model2.add(layers.Dense(output_classes, activation='relu'))

comb_model = Sequential()

x1=model1.output
x2=model2.output
comb_model.layers.Concatenate([x1,x2],axis=-1)
comb_model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
comb_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.6))
comb_model.add(layers.Dense(output_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

print(comb_model.summary())
```

error shown is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-267f93f5102f> in <module>()
      3 x1=model1.output
      4 x2=model2.output
----> 5 comb_model.layers.Concatenate([x1,x2],axis=-1)
      6 comb_model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
      7 comb_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.6))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Concatenate'
```

Comment: you forgot to add your error? and your code is not complete, I guess

Comment: @BashirKazimi, i have edited the question and included the error as well.

Comment: Check out what I have posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create your combined model like this instead?

```
x1=model1.output
x2=model2.output
concat = layers.Concatenate()([x1,x2])
dense1 = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(concat)
dropout = layers.Dropout(0.6)(dens1)
dense2 = layers.Dense(output_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(dropout)
comb_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input], outputs=dense2)
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Now model.fit is not working for me   ```  base_model1 = model.fit_generator(["train_generator","train_generator"], steps_per_epoch = 
    nb_train_samples // batch_size, epochs = epochs, validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = nb_validation_samples // batch_size) ```

Comment: First of all, that is a separate problem and needs a new question. Second of all, please check some guidelines on how to properly ask a question here and report your issues. People should be able to reproduce your code and errors in order to be able to help you.

Comment: sorry. being new to this, i am not that aware of the things here. i have posted this as a new question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406988/model-fit-generator-for-dual-path-cnn

Comment: No problem, we have all been there. I have just provided an answer to your question there. Hope it works

Comment: pls see this qn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61577390/trying-to-add-an-input-layer-to-cnn-model-in-keras

Comment: can u pls look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034278/error-in-multiplying-2-tensorflow-cnn-layers-with-different-dimensions-for-atten