# Error in multiplying 2 tensorflow cnn layers with different dimensions for attention cnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I wanted to multiply(find dot product) the output from 2 cnn layers. Unfortunately both have different dimensions. Can any one help with resizing of the tensors?

My base model is

```
model_base = Sequential()
# Conv Layer 1
model_base.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(32, (9, 9), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model_base.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# Conv Layer 2
model_base.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(64, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model_base.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

# Conv Layer 3
model_base.add(layers.SeparableConv2D(128, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model_base.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

model_base.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
# model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
# Flatten the data for upcoming dense layer
#model_base.add(layers.Flatten())
#model_base.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
#model_base.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))

print(model_base.summary())
```

output from layer 2 and layer 6 are taken and tried multiplication

```
c1 = model_base.layers[2].output 
c1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(c1)  
p=np.shape(c1)
c3 = model_base.layers[6].output 
c3 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(c3)  
x = keras.layers.multiply([c1, c3])
```

Getting error since both are of different dimensions. How will I multiply ?

Comment: can u change layer 6 to have an output dim of 64 instead of 256 ?

Comment: There is no way we can resize tensor outputs?

Comment: u can also apply a Dense(64)(c3) after c3 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(c3) and before than multiply

Comment: Now i am able to multiply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to compute multiplication, u have to have two tensors with the same dimensionality. here a possibility (following your model_base structure):

```
c1 = model_base.layers[2].output 
c1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(c1)  

c3 = model_base.layers[6].output 
c3 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(c3)
c3 = Dense(c1.shape[-1])(c3)

x = Multiply()([c1, c3])
```